# Integrate Multi-Channel Sales With Magento API

Tags: magento

Looking for advice on the sequence of Magento API calls necessary to implement this business process:

1. An inventory item (either physical or virtual/digital) is made available by the seller via an external channel (not the regular web storefront).
2. A customer initiates a payment directly to me without going through the Magento cart / checkout flow (can I lookup sales tax at this point?)
3. After the payment has been made, I want to trigger Magento post-processing logic to record the sale, manage inventory, etc.
4. For physical goods, I want to trigger Magento fulfillment logic to occur to create the shipment, etc.

I'm aware of the SOAP API, I'm looking for help to understand which actions need to be taken along the way to enact this process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is very basic example how Magento API can be used for your case:

1. Connect to Magento via API

   $user = 'apiUser'; $password = 'apiKey';
    
   $proxy = new SoapClient('http://your_magento_host.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
    
   $sessionId = $proxy->login($user, $password);
2. Create or select customer

   // Create customer
    
   $customerList = $proxy->customerCustomerCreate($sessionId, 
    array(
    'email' => 'customer@gmail.com', 
    'firstname' => 'Will', 
    'lastname' => 'Smith', 
    'password' => 'qwerty', 
    'website_id' => 1, 
    'store_id' => 1, 
    'group_id' => 1
    ));
    
   $customer = (array) $customerList[0];
    
   $customer['mode'] = 'customer';

   // Or select existing customer (by email)
    
   $filter = array(
    
       'complex_filter' => array(
    
           array(
    
               'key' => 'email',
    
               'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => 'customer@gmail.com')
    
           )
       ) );
    
   $customerList = $proxy->customerCustomerList($sessionId, $filter);
    
   $customer = (array) $customerList[0];
    
   $customer['mode'] = 'customer';
3. Create cart

   $cartId = $proxy->shoppingCartCreate($sessionId, 1); 
    
   $proxy->shoppingCartCustomerSet($sessionId, $cartId, $customer);
4. Select product (by sku)

   $filter = array(
    
       'complex_filter' => array(
    
           array(
    
               'key' => 'sku',
    
               'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => 'T-SHIRT001')
    
           )
       ) );
    
   $productList = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId, $filter);
    
   $product = (array) $productList[0];
    
   $product['qty'] = 1;
5. Add product to cart

   $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId, $cartId, array($product));
6. Set billing/shipping address. You should add this addresses to customer if you just create it before.

   $address = array(
    
           array(
    
               'mode' => 'shipping',
    
               'firstname' => $customer['firstname'],
    
               'lastname' => $customer['lastname'],
    
               'street' => 'street address',
    
               'city' => 'city',
    
               'region' => 'region',
    
               'telephone' => 'phone number',
    
               'postcode' => 'postcode',
    
               'country_id' => 'country ID',
    
               'is_default_shipping' => 0,
    
               'is_default_billing' => 0
    
           ),
    
           array(
    
               'mode' => 'billing',
    
               'firstname' => $customer['firstname'],
    
               'lastname' => $customer['lastname'],
    
               'street' => 'street address',
    
               'city' => 'city',
    
               'region' => 'region',
    
               'telephone' => 'phone number',
    
               'postcode' => 'postcode',
    
               'country_id' => 'country ID',
    
               'is_default_shipping' => 0,
    
               'is_default_billing' => 0
    
           ),
       );

   $proxy->shoppingCartCustomerAddresses($sessionId, $cartId, $address);
7. Set shipping mathod

   $proxy->shoppingCartShippingMethod($sessionId, $cartId, 'flatrate_flatrate');
8. Set payment method.

   $paymentMethod =  array(
    
           'po_number' => null,
    
           'method' => 'checkmo',
    
           'cc_cid' => null,
    
           'cc_owner' => null,
    
           'cc_number' => null,
    
           'cc_type' => null,
    
           'cc_exp_year' => null,
    
           'cc_exp_month' => null
    
       );

   $proxy->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($sessionId, $cartId, $paymentMethod);
9. Place order

   $orderId = $proxy->shoppingCartOrder($sessionId, $cartId, null, null);

Now check Sales->Orders in Magento admin area and you'll see new order.
 
More details here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you if there is a SOAP API call that I could use to have Magento calculate the sales tax based on the shipping address (the rules vary by locality in the US)?

Comment: Yes, it will calculate Tax during shoppingCartOrder() call. Just provide correct data on previous steps and set Tax settings in Magento Admin area (Sales->Tax and System->Configuration).

Comment: Is there any way to get the tax amount before finalizing the order? Since I am taking payments in a separate channel, I would either need to: 1) "create" orders to calculate the tax amount and then cancel the orders for any user that abandons payment, or 2) find another alternative for looking up the tax rate without calling shoppingCartOrder().

Comment: Great - also, I presume that setting the payment method with 'method' => 'checkmo' means to expect an external payment (like a physical check). Is there a SOAP API for marking that payment as received along with a correlation id?

Comment: 'checkmo' is Magento's "Check / Money Order" payment method: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuration-payment-methods-check-money-order     Usually, this method used when payment just should be placed in Magento without dealing with any external payment gateways.

Comment: About correlation id: you can add comment to order with all needed additional data like real transaction ID etc: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.addComment.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can catch information about Tax:

1) Without order saving. Step 9:

```
$result = $proxy->shoppingCartTotals($sessionId, $cartId);<br>
var_dump($result);
```

You'll see array of subtotal, taxes, discounts and total.

2) With order saving. Step 10:

```
$result = $proxy->salesOrderInfo($sessionId, $orderId);<br>
var_dump($result);

// cancel order<br>
$result = $proxy->salesOrderCancel($sessionId, $orderId);
```

More information about used API calls here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.totals.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.cancel.html